# Block defined in page.xml do not render

Tags: php, xml, layout, magento

I have made a custom block in Magento that contains some JS. I want to have it placed right after `<head>` in output HTML. Block looks like this:

```
<?php if($this->isHomePage()): ?>
<script language='JavaScript1.1' type='text/javascript'>ns_loadingtime1=(new Date()).getTime()</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

In a `page.xml` file of my template I have this:

```
(...)
<block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/2columns-left.phtml">
            <block type="baobaz_tags/widget_nedstattag_metadata" name="baobaz_nedstattag_head" as="nedstattagHead" before="head" template="baobaz/tags/widget/nedstattag/homepage/meta.phtml" />
            <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
```

In output HTML my custom block (`baobaz_nedstattag_head`) don't exists. Do you know what can I do to render it as I wish?

**EDIT** Thanks to comment of Fabrizio I was able to make it right. Because in his approach I was getting double entry of my block. So I left the page.xml as it's written above and I have added to 1column.phtml `$this->getChildHtml('nedstattagHead')` before calling `head` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to move the block definition inside the head block definition:

```
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
     <block type="baobaz_tags/widget_nedstattag_metadata" name="baobaz_nedstattag_head" as="nedstattagHead" template="baobaz/tags/widget/nedstattag/homepage/meta.phtml"  before="-" />

 ... missing code of head block definition ...
</block>
```

Make sure you add the `echo $this->getChildHtml('nedstattagHead')` in the `page/html/head.phtml` file.

Comment: Yeah! Just right what I needed :) `getChildHtml()`, why I didn't think about it!?